# /.?e.?/ matches entire string, rather than expected substring

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

In Internet Explorer 10, this:

```
'abcdefghi'.match(/.?e.?/)
```

evaluates to `['def']`, as I'd expect, but in Firefox 21.0, it evaluates to `['abcdefghi']`. (See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gKve/2/).) I get the same sort of unexpected behavior for certain other regexes that both begin and end with optional content, such as `/.?e.{0,2}/` and `/.{0,2}e.{0,2}/`; however, commenters point out various similar regexes, such as `/\S?e\S?/` and `/(?:.?e.?)/`, that are *not* affected. The same applies to the `replace` method.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there some deep reason for this behavior?

Comment: Well in chrome its: `e
de
ef
cdef` +1 for this one.

Comment: Well, adding a group seems to *correct* it: `'abcdefghi'.match(/(?:.?e.?)/)`. But, I'm guessing bug.

Comment: Same issue shows up in Firefox 22, but it should be noted that `/.?.?/` works properly, as does `/e.?/` and `/.?e/`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, Which version of chrome do you use? I get `['def']` in *chrome 28.0.1500.72*.

Comment: @falsetru: Burhan Khalid is referring to the results of my Fiddle, which has `.{0,2}e.?` instead of `.?e.?`, resulting in `cdef` instead of the `def` I stated in the question. I'll update the Fiddle to remove the inconsistency.

Comment: FWIW in the latest Firefox (22) its still showing `'abcdefghi'`, but with `'abcdefghi'.match(/.?(e.?)/)` it groups it correctly; this is odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As tiffon said, this is a bug in SpiderMonkey (Firefox's JavaScript engine).

In SpiderMonkey, we use the RegExp engine from Safari's JavaScriptCore JS engine, and inherited the bug from that. I filed [bug 119191](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=119191) for the bug in JSC.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug. I filed [an issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=898823).

Btw, the following work fine:

```
'abcdefghi'.match(/.e./)
'abcdefghi'.match(/.e.?/)
'abcdefghi'.match(/.?e./)
'abcdefghi'.match(/[a-z]?e.?/)
'abcdefghi'.match(/.?e[a-z]?/)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afDqC/1/

Comment: +1, thank you! It's unfortunate that I can't accept two answers . . .

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers stated, it appears to be a bug.

However, there's an easy workaround available: `'abcdefghi'.match(/(.?e.?)/)`

That way you get correct results in both `[0]` (the implicit subgroup containing the whole string the regex matched) and `[1]` (the subgroup specified by `()`)

Comment: Indeed, Jonathan Lonowski had pointed this out in a comment above (though he had suggested using a non-capture group, `/(?:.?e.?)/`, which has *no* effect other than working around this bug).